# Repeat single char to char array. set length of array to match the needed length for string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am using a scanner to input a single char. This char will need to be repeated as many times as needed to build a specific shape. 
ex:

```
AAAAA   <<< this would be a square made from the char A
AAAAA
AAAAA
```

I have a superclass Shape and subclasses square, diamond, circle.
`shapeString` is the public static var used in Shape to display the string built depending on which char is used. Here is my for-loop to set the length of the array needed. I need help with setting the length of the array to the loop size.

```
System.out.println("Type an upper or lower case letter or one of these special characters: !, #, $, %, &, (, ), *, + Press ENTER");
setChar = input.next(); 
char[] stringSetChar = setChar.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < shapeString.length(); i++ {
  stringSetChar.length([i]); // help here!
  shapeString = new String(stringSetChar);
}
```

Comment: ok obviously I thought you would be able to see how the A's made the shape of a square. Ha ha. Sorry

Comment: Use `java.util.Scanner.nextLine() ` method instead. It will be easier.

Comment: Is the size of the shape always the same?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a "template" String passed to the constructor of `Shape`, and have `Shape` implement a `draw()` method that uses the template to create the output by replacing place-holder chars with the desired char:

```
abstract class Shape {
    private final String template;

    protected Shape(String template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void draw(char c) {
        System.out.println(template.replace('.', c));
    }
}

class Square extends Shape {
    public Square() {
        super(".....\n.....\n.....\n");
    }
}
```

These approach allows drawing arbitrary shapes (eg letters, emoticons etc).

---

Some test code:

```
new Square().draw('A');
```

Output:

```
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
```